# Accton SMCWUSB-G 802.11bg Wireless adapter does not initialize

Tags: wireless, usb

I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows.

If I shutdown my PC, and then turn on and boot in Ubuntu, my USB wireless adapter does not initialize. I currently have 2 workaround:

1. Unplug USB adapter, then plug in (while in Ubuntu session)
2. Boot in Windows, which doesn't have this problem, then restart (without turning PC off) and boot in Ubuntu

I use mainly second option, but would appreciate real solution to this problem.

If I just reboot Ubuntu, without tuning PC off, then everything is fine

Here is **update** information:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 083a:4505 Accton Technology Corp. SMCWUSB-G 802.11bg


$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network               
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
     logical name: eth0
     version: 02
     size: 100Mbit/s
     capacity: 100Mbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
     resources: irq:40 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdeff000-fdefffff memory:fdee0000-fdeeffff memory:febe0000-febfffff
*-network
     description: Wireless interface
     physical id: 1
     bus info: usb@1:2
     logical name: wlan0
     capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=zd1211rw driverversion=2.6.38-13-generic firmware=4725 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Second **update:**

I compared dmesg logs from successful init, and from init failure, and here is what seemed relevant to me:

First in both logs is line:

```
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
```

which I assume is referencing this WLAN adapter, and then only in session that failed to init my wlan adapter:

```
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 17
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 18
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 19
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 20
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 22
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 23
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 27
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 31
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 32
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 33
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 37
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 43
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 44
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 48
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 49
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 51
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 57
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 58
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 65
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 72
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 78
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 79
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 84
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 85
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 86
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 87
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 89
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 93
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Regards,

Comment: Do I need to provide more info? I also noticed that turning PC Off and then On after short time interval (like couple of minutes, or half hour), there are no issues and adapter is initialized fine. Problem happens after shutting down for longer period, what ever that may mean.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the $Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: `Unable to enumerate USB device` is a USB-level communication error. Check cables, hubs, radio interference, power issues, etc. This is not a wireless issue.

Comment: As @Seth points out this is abandoned but is also based on EOL Ubuntu version based on date of question. Plus there are zero answers. As such VTC as not reproducible.